# Cannot ping any whm IP addresses

Tags: dns, timeout, ping, whm, traceroute

I have set up WHM and have one site on cPanel, which I can FTP into and browse without problems. However, I can't ping the server IP or the domain. I've checked all the settings and everything seems OK. If I try to traceroute a domain, it eventually returns a lot of 0.0.0.0 results but doesn't return the server IP.
I am not using private nameservers, just the ones provided by the hosting company. The domains for both the web site and the WHM hostname have A records pointing to the server IP. These appear in the WHM DNS zones, and I also manually added them in the DNS settings for each domain at the hosting company.

I am concerned this is part of a bigger problem somewhere in my WHM setup. I don't know why I can reach a domain and log into WHM, but I can't ping either. I also don't receive any server emails, they won't send so I wonder if this is an associated problem?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was this: the reason I was unable to ping the server was because I had not allowed ICMP traffic through the server firewall. ICMP is the protocol used by ping and traceroute so therefore neither worked.

Having added a rule for this, ping and traceroute now work.